# Не работает Array.Copy

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Добрый день, попытался использовать метод Array.Copy или Array.ConstrainedCopy
обнаружил что он копирует всего 15% значений многомерного массива

```cs
Array.Copy(source, destination, size);
Array.ConstrainedCopy(source, 0, destination, 0, size);
```

при этом если копировать вот так

```cs
for (int i = 1; i <= size - 1; i++)
{
    destination[i, 0] = source[i,0];
    destination[i, 1] = source[i,1];
    destination[i, 2] = source[i,2];
    destination[i, 3] = source[i,3];
    destination[i, 4] = source[i,4];
    destination[i, 5] = source[i,5];
    destination[i, 6] = source[i,6];
    destination[i, 7] = source[i,7];
    destination[i, 8] = source[i,8];
    destination[i, 9] = source[i,9];
    destination[i, 10] = source[i,10];
    destination[i, 11] = source[i,11];
    destination[i, 12] = source[i,12];
    destination[i, 13] = source[i,13];
    destination[i, 14] = source[i,14];
    destination[i, 15] = source[i,15];
    destination[i, 16] = source[i,16];
    destination[i, 17] = source[i,17];
    destination[i, 18] = source[i,18];
    destination[i, 19] = source[i,19];
    destination[i, 20] = source[i,20];
    destination[i, 21] = source[i,21];
    destination[i, 22] = source[i,22];
    destination[i, 23] = source[i,23];
}
```

все работает, все копирует, но разница в размерах написанного очевидна, в чем может быть проблема

Comment: А покажите, какие у вас типы аргументов, а? И какие значения? Может быть, вы неправильно вычисляете длину?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3-м параметром надо указывать общее количество элементов: Для двумерного массива это:

```
Array.Copy(source, destination,  
           numberOfRows * numberOfColumns);
```

В вашем случае должно быть:

```
Array.Copy(source, destination,  
           size * 24);
```

> В процессе копирования из одного многомерного массива в другой, массив ведет себя как длинный одномерный массив, в котором строки (или столбцы) рассматриваются как расположенные последовательно друг за другом. [(MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/k4yx47a1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: я делал перемножение общего количества элементов но вот условие, для его выполнения не достигалось, спасибо PashaPash, правильная мысль

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложил так

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= GetDataStructur.Item1 - 1; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j <= 23; j++)
      {
        ValueProcessInfo.GetDataStructurOld[i, j] = GetDataStructur.Item2[i,j];
      }
    }
```

В смысле руками прокопировать все
Я вижу, что тут двумерный массив GetDataStructur.Item2[i,23]
Я не знаю, как Array.Copy работает, но не думаю, что он умеет двумерные массивы

Comment: но 15 % -  20 % он все же корректно копирует ???

Comment: Да, вон @PashaPash рассказал. Всего элементов  GetDataStructur.Item1*23, а изначально у Вас передается параметром  GetDataStructur.Item1.